# @Font-face dynamic loading of <link (...)>. Working everywhere(Chrome, IE8, Safari) EXCEPT FIREFOX!

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, font-face, dynamic-loading

I'm making a plugin for wordpress. I'm dynamically loading font to tinymce

```
//load font to iframe
function loadFontFace(fontId)
{

    var iframe = jQ('#content_ifr').contents();
    var head = iframe[0].getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var linkElement = jQ(document.createElement('link'));
    linkElement.attr({href: 'http://fontsforweb.com/font/generatecss/?id=' + fontId, rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css'});
    linkElement.prependTo(head);
}
```

Works everywhere except Firefox! Firebug in network tab shows that CSS and also TTF font files are loaded but I see no effect.

I'm not going to use webfont loader because it's ALMOST working.

Comment: can you post the contents of the @font face declarations

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|woff|ttf)$">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</FilesMatch>
```

Solved the problem

---

After HOURS of SEARCHING it looks like I'm getting there! I can see that TFF file in firebug's net tab has only 1KB. But it have 17KB. Solution will be here soon by myself I hope:)

Edit 30 mins later
These are file details from net panel firebug:

> my font(not working):
>   Content-Encoding    gzip
>   Server  Apache
>   Etag    "225c018-4448-480e34c5df480"
>   Accept-Ranges   bytes
>   Content-Type    text/plain
>   Age 176
>   Date    Wed, 19 Jan 2011 23:03:31 GMT
>   Last-Modified   Wed, 03 Mar 2010 10:53:54 GMT
>   Expires Thu, 20 Jan 2011 23:03:31 GMT
>   Transfer-Encoding   chunked
>
> google font(working):
>   Content-Type    font/ttf
>   Content-Encoding    gzip
>   Expires Thu, 20 Jan 2011 16:45:42 GMT
>   Date    Wed, 19 Jan 2011 16:45:42 GMT
>   Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
>   Last-Modified   Tue, 21 Sep 2010 17:51:21 GMT
>   Content-Length  20232
>   Content-Disposition attachment; filename="Cuprum.ttf"
>   X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
>   X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
>   X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
>   Server  GSE
>   Cache-Control   public, max-age=86400
>   Age 23113
>   Connection  keep-alive